# Which to use - concat or assignment operator or join by?

Tags: javascript, string

I am stuck on this one particular problem, with trying to figure out how to combine my newnumString and nextnumString with a "&". After trying a couple of things out, I decided to use the assignment operator + but it's not giving me the desired output. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
function decrementAnd(num) {
  var newnumArray = [];
  for (var i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
    newnumArray.push(i);
    var newnumString = newnumArray.join("");//987654321

      for (var j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
      newnumArray.push(j);
      var nextnumString = newnumArray.join("");//98765432187654321..

      }
    }
  console.log(newnumString + "&" + nextnumString)
}
decrementAnd(9);
```

Expected output:

```
// 5="54321&4321&321&21&1"
// 3="321&21&1"
// 9="987654321&87654321&7654321&654321&54321&4321&321&21&1"
```

Comment: What language is this, JavaScript? It would help to walk through a couple examples: how you expect to call your function (inputs), what it currently does (current output), and what you expect it to do (expected output).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the joins and works with arrays, you can work just with a string. Here is an example:

```js
function decrementAnd(num) {
  var numbers = "";
  for (var i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (var j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
         numbers += j;
      }
      numbers+="&";
  }
  //Delete last &
  return numbers.slice(0,-1);
}

console.log("3=", decrementAnd(3));
console.log("5=", decrementAnd(5));
console.log("9=", decrementAnd(9));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without using arrays, if you store the intermediate result you can do it with a single loop:

```js
function decrementAnd(num) {
  var result="", numbers="";
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    numbers=i.toString()+numbers;
    result=numbers+"&"+result;
  }
  result=result.substring(0,result.length-1); // removing extra "&" at the end
  console.log(result);
}
decrementAnd(3);
decrementAnd(5);
decrementAnd(9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out!!!

```js
function decrementAnd(num) {
  var newStrinArray = [];
  for(var i= num; i>=1;i--){
  var newnumArray = [];
  for(var j= i; j>=1;j--){
  newnumArray.push(j);
  }
  newStrinArray.push(newnumArray.join("") + "&"); 
  }
  console.log(newStrinArray.join(""));
}
decrementAnd(9);
```